# plot in python Piecewise function substitution

Tags: python, piecewise

I want to plot a graph in python by substituting piecewise function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
%matplotlib inline
#set up constants
d0=0.2
d1=0.2
L0=0.2
L=5
delta1=0.02
Dp=1
def fun(x):
    out = np.zeros_like(x)
    out[(x >= 0) & (x <= d1)] = d0
    mask = (x >= d1) & (x <= d1 + L0)
    out[mask] = d0-0.5*delta1*(1+np.cos(2*np.pi/L0)*(x[mask]-d1-0.5*L0))
    out[(x >= d1 + L0) & (x <= L)] = L0
    return out

# Define 100 points between 0 to 5 evenly       spaced
y = np.linspace(0, 5, 100) # Change
g = Dp*(y*y-(fun(y))**2) # Change
plt.plot(y, g) # Change
plt.show() # Change
```

[image]

dear fun(y)is not a function of y its a function of x. i am attaching the sample graph

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What exactly are you having trouble with?  Do you want to use `fun` to make a plot?   This - `g = Dp*(y*y-fun^2):` is invalid syntax.

Comment: fun(x) is a function which i defined as piecewise function . i want to substitute in g and plot a graph and y range from  0 to 5

Comment: dear  i am new to python codings.see the changes and thanks in advance .

Comment: Your code is running perfectly. If the function is not the function you expect, how can we help?

Comment: @Giovanni Tardini
The codes mentioned above are correct or not  based on the equations.

Comment: @rayryeng
please see the equations and graph which i have uploaded. Based on the equations  the codes are correct or not because you have mentioned in the codes g = Dp*(y*y-(fun(y))**2) but the equation is  u = Dp*(y*y-(fun(x))**2)

Comment: `out[(x >= d1 + L0) & (x <= L)] = L0`

seems wrong anyway, because you do not have L0 as f-value in your equation. They happen to have the same value in your code, but that's a bug. My other question is:
are the brackets for the cos function right? Is only 2 pi / L0 inside the cos argument, or should that include also x - d1 - L0/2, as I believe? Then your f is wrong

Comment: @Giovanni Tardini
out[(x >= d1 + L0) & (x <= L)] = d0 .where L0 and d0 are constant. where as cos function  cos(2 pi / L0*( x - d1 - L0/2)), please see the equations as i mentioned above